# how to simulate print process in c

Tags: c, process, pipe, pthreads

my project consiste of creating a C program that simulates print process , means that N processes are attempting to print a file in the screen.
-each process should send its file through a pipe to the main process in charge of printing.
-the main process sends approval signals to the processes in FIFO  ordre so they can access to the pipe.
-the processes SHOULD NOT BE BLOCKED , they can execute something else while waiting for the approval signal . 
Here is my unfinished code 
my questions are : 
-how to notify the other processes.
-is it enough to use mutex lock or i need another way to synchronize threads in my case ?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#define n 4
#define max 5


int pipefd[2];
char buf[max+1] = {'\0'};
pthread_mutex_t mut;

//the print function is for testing (unfinished)
void *PrintFunc(){
        if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mut)==0){
        char *msg="hello";
        
        write(pipefd[1],msg,max);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    
}

int main(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL);
    int i;
    pthread_t idt;
    pid_t ID;

    if(pipe(pipefd)<0) { exit(1);}  
    //create 4 processes
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(ID!=0){  
            ID = fork();
            
            if(ID == -1){
            perror("Erreur fork\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
            }
        }           
    }
        //create 1 thread for each process to handdle the print 
        if(ID==0){
        
        close(pipefd[0]);
        pthread_create(&idt, NULL, PrintFunc,NULL);
        pthread_join(idt, NULL);
        
        }
    

    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        wait(NULL);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        read(pipefd[0],buf ,max);
        printf("%s\n",buf);
        memset(buf,'\0',max+1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

any help will be appreciated , Thank you!

Comment: You should think about your concept of processes (`fork`) and threads(`pthread_create`). Probably you don't need threads. Describe your concept in an abstract way. How are the N processes supposed to share the work? There are different ways to send notifications from the main process to the children. It is diffcult to recommend something without knowing the details.

Comment: `ID` is tested before it is initialized. I guess you should initialize it to a non-zero value.

Comment: basically , only one process should have access to the pipe at once , so the others should wait untill the pipe is free , the next process to use the pipe will be notified then

Comment: The simplest "approval signal" is probably a POSIX signal raised by the parent for a particular child and handled in the child processes. It is slightly open to abuse because some other process with sufficient privilege could send the signal, but the child could check that the `si_pid` member of the `siginfo_t` matches the parent's PID.

Comment: i will try with this, thank you !